# how to copy a content of file placed in remote server in variable of shell script at local machine

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I am running my script from machineA and creating the logfile accordingly. As per script requirement need to navigate to MachineB by doing ssh (made passwordless with keygen). Maintaining separate logfile at MachineB. Now I want to merge logfile in machineB with logfile in machineA. As I am not able to make the scp from MachineB to MachineA passwordless, hence thinking of a workaround to store content of logfile in MachineB in a variable and then assign the value to local variable which can later be used to append in logfile of MachineA.

Below is the extract from code :

```
a="$(ssh userw@server.com "
y=$("<"$logfileMachineB);
exit")"
```

Output : `"-bash: logfileMachineB: No such file or directory`

Also, tried doing ==`cat $logfileMachineB` but same error.

Please help to achieve the requirement.

Answer (score 4):

To store the contents of a remote file to a variable on your local machine, you can do:

```
a=$(ssh user@remote "cat file")
```

You can now `echo "$a"` on the local machine and see the contents of the remote file.

As William points out in the comments, it is a good idea in general to enclose command substitutions `$()` in double quotes, to prevent problems associated with [word splitting](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/wordsplit).

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that it is safe to not put quotes around `$()` in this case because it is a simple variable assignment and word splitting is not performed, but in many other settings double quotes around the `$()` would be required.

Comment: @kapil if your problem is solved, don't forget to accept my answer by clicking on the check mark ✔ next to it.